# Android text to be share using share intent on Facebook status

Tags: android, facebook, share

I want to share text not link to facebook. Ya we can share links. But if i have simple text then it has to be set to facebook post edittext. Is it possible to do that? if yes then please suggest me... how??? Thank you.

Comment: You are not allowed to specify the message part of any post – it has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a text, not a link, in facebook you have to use their library to do it because they "remove" the share text when you send a normal Intent, at least in the past years... they change very often.

You can download and follow the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Other solution is use a library that helps you include easily social libraries like ASNE library

https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE
Its a little outdated but is very easy to improve